# Get GitHub Asciidoc to recognize a file link to a Windows NAS share

Tags: github, asciidoc

I have a Windows NAS drive that has lots of shared folders and documents, and I want to link to them from a GitHub Wiki written in Asciidoc.  Intuitively, the link would be this:

```
link:file://my.corp.location/foo/bar/SomeFolder/[]
```

That "file://..." is recognized by both Windows Explorer and Browsers such as Chrome.  But the GitHub Wiki doesn't seem to recognize it.  I've tried several patterns such as changing "file" to "http" and so on, but can't get it.

I'm on our corporate GitHub, which I know has some restrictions in rendering that the industry GitHub.com doesn't.  But I know we use the same underlying software and our versions stay pretty up to date.

**How do I link to a Windows NAS location from GitHub Wiki in Asciidoc?**

Thanks!